# Left Join on multiple columns Django model ORM foreign key

Tags: django, orm, foreign-keys, left-join

I am trying to understand the Django ORM.

I have 3 models that I am trying to join.

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Movie(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Recommendation(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rec1 = models.ForeignKey(Movie, related_name='rec1', 
     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rec2 = models.ForeignKey(Movie, related_name='rec2', 
     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now in my `Recommendation` I have 2 fields that are recommendations (`rec1` and `rec2`) and correspond to `Movie.id`. I want to join these models to be able to show the movie.title and movie.genre for each recommendation (for each user, with their user information).

I tried using two Foreign Keys, but got errors on the `related_name` and now this error: `Cannot assign "8": "Recommendation.rec1" must be a "Movie" instance.` I don't think I fully understand the concept of how to join these models.

In SQL I would use a LEFT JOIN on `rec1 = Movie.id` and `rec2 = Movie.id`, but I don't understand how to implement this in the Django ORM.

Expected outcome

```
User 1, gender 'F': recommendations 'Lion King', 'Batman'
```

Comment: Shouldn't `rec1` and `rec2` be `ForeignKey`s then? By using a `ForeignKey` Django can make convenient queries for this.

Comment: Yeah I tried that. Got an error: ```Cannot assign "8": "Recommendation.rec1" must be a "Movie" instance.```, and don't understand how to circumvent this

Comment: well as the error says, by using a `ForeignKey`, you set instance objects to these fields, or you use `rec1_id` to set the primary key of that instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ForeignKey` to the `Movie` model

```
class Recommendation(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rec1 = models.ForeignKey(Movie, related_name="recommendations1")
    rec2 = models.ForeignKey(Movie, related_name="recommendations2")
```

Then you can get what you are looking for like this, for example:

```
rec = Recommendation.objects.first()
rec.user.gender
rec.rec1.title
```

Also, make sure that use a `Movie` object instance when you assign the movie to the `rec1` or `rec2` field:

```
movie = Movie.objects.first()
rec.rec1 = movie
rec.save()
```

**EDIT:**
To get the model object when you have the ID you can do the following:

```
rec.rec1 = Movie.objects.get(id=row['rec1'])
rec.save()
```

Comment: Okay, I do not know how to do the last part. When I try to fill my recommendations model I used ```rec.rec1 = row['rec1']```, but I understand from your answer that is incorrect and causing the error. I see now that I should figure out how to fill the ```rec.rec1``` with an instance of my ```Movie model``` that matches the ```Movie.id```

Comment: What does `row` contain? How do you create movie objects?

Comment: row is a Pandas dataframe I am looping through and contains the ```Movie.id``` recommendation that I am doing for that user. Movie objects are imported and created from a csv file.

Comment: Does the movie with that id exist in the DB at the time the user is making the selection?

Comment: Yes it does exist at the time the user is making the selection. Actually all of my data (User, Movie and Recommendation) exists beforehand, I am just trying to dump it in a SQL database and display it in a view. I am thinking it should be this ```rec.rec1 = Movie.objects.get(id=row['rec1'])```, will test now

Comment: Ah i see you've updated the comment! Thank you very much!!